# Are there residential light switches that don't have a arc upon toggleing

Tags: electrical

I am looking for residential switches that don't arc when toggeled

Comment: Why is it going to be around a ignitable gas mixture? Perhaps you want a _explosion proof switch_ which has sealed contacts.

Comment: No not around a gas mixture.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not find a typical wall switch that totally eliminates the little arc when switching a load. This is inherent in a switch.

You can use a heavy duty, or "spec-grade", switch that has a much more solid and distinct switch mechanism. This may at least mask the arcing.

May I ask why you are looking for this?

Comment: Back before everyone became terrified of the stuff, we had ones that kept the arc entirely inside the little glass capsule with the mercury... ;-)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_switch#Mercury_switch

Comment: I had been exposed to the mercury switches before but haven't been able to find them.

Comment: You won't find them any more.

Comment: There is some on that big auction site right now..

Answer (score 1):

If this is not for an explosive atmosphere, you could use a wall switch from those X10 home control systems. I am guessing they still have a small low voltage arc that would make them unsafe for explosive atmospheres but there is no arc in the 110v path.

Comment: The X10 (and Insteon, and probably other dimmable switches used in home automation use an electronic switch, so there are no contacts, and therefore no arc.  The non-dimmable switches have a relay, so there may be an arc with them).

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to the traditional analog based toggle switches that do arc, Lutron's electronic Maestro® products do NOT arc. However, the style comes only in the "decor" style and not the traditional toggle.  As with most electronic switches and dimmers, many require a neutral at the switch location junction box.  Keep that in mind before starting any major renovations

Also keep in mind that Lutron electronic switches require a minimum of 40 watts with LEDs

Comment: Also, with Lutron electronic switches the minimum load when using LEDs is 40 Watts.  This basically makes using LEDs with them impossible unless it's a large LED project.  Just a another heads up for you if you're doing a renovation.

Answer (score 0):

It is not the switch that make the arc, it is the load. With electromechanical switches, you're unable to eliminate electrical arc except if you use specific load. I have checked that with a led light 4W lamp which have no inrush current I have no arc at make and break contact.